# Loading all files in a directory onto webpage ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, directory, filenames

So I have the following code that is supposed to match a regular expression to the files in a directory and output all the file names that match the regular expression.  However, I think my regex might be wrong.  It is supposed to output files of the form [content]_[model name]_[more content], but it's currently not displaying anything.

Code:

```
        string pattern = @".*"+Request.QueryString["model"]+@".*";
        String myPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
        var matches = Directory.GetFiles(myPath+@"All Plots 1 Year\").Where(path => Regex.Match(path, pattern).Success);
        foreach (var f in matches)
        {
            Response.Write(f);
            Response.Write("<br />");
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of Request.QueryString["model"]?

Comment: You can debug it step by step to find the issue by your self. What is not found here ? the files, the directory, the permission, the query string is wrong... ? even the response.write maybe fail... so debug debug debug, step by step...

Comment: Request.QueryString["model"] is giving back a string such as 2k01 or 3s02, its coming in as a GET parameter from another page which is loading this content dynamically using Jquery.  I know that the page is being loaded, because I can do something like Response.Write("hello world") and it pops up, and I can list out the entire directory when I'm not parsing the filenames with a regular expression, so I'm sure it has something to do with an incorrectly formed regular expression, or theres something wrong with how I'm applying it.

Comment: Use a tool to help design and learn regex, like >> http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your regex is that simple, then skip regex, skip linq and use >>

```
Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(myPath, @"All Plots 1 Year\"), "*" + Request.QueryString["model"] + "*")
```